# UPDATE table problem with email address

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a email field in Mysql through php.
i keep getting this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@yahoo.com,`

The cell in Mysql is varchar(100).
The e-mail addres is typed in from a text box.

`$insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email=".$_POST['email']", WHERE id='$user->id'";`

with the previous code, mysql updates only half of the email address, only the `@yahoo.com` part.

i tried to convert $_POST['email'] to string and the result is the error i wrote.

EDIT:

Thanks guys, you're great!

I found out what it was... bad syntax and forgot to escape.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you seem to have a syntax error in the code (no dot after `$_POST['email']`).

And the variable itself isn't surrounded by quotes.
It should be:

```
$insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email='{$_POST['email']}', WHERE id='$user->id'";
```

Also, don't forget to escape the variable using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
$_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']).
```

Answer (score 3):

I see three errors:

- String value must be enclosed in quotes:

  ```
  $insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email='".$_POST['email']"', WHERE id='$user->id'";
  //                                     ---^               ---^
  ```
- Missing string concatenation:

  ```
  $insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email='".$_POST['email']."', WHERE id='$user->id'";
  //                                                       ---^
  ```
- Remove the comma:

  ```
  $insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email='".$_POST['email']."'  WHERE id='$user->id'";
  //                                                          ---^
  ```

As already mentioned, don't forget to use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: And Ye Gods man.. don't forget to escape. The filter_input functions are great: http://www.phparch.com/2010/07/08/never-use-_get-again/

Answer (score 1):

Always escape input:

```
$insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($user->id)."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In that exact query string I can see a problem.

```
$insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email=".$_POST['email']", WHERE id='$user->id'";
```

You need to add a '.' after $_POST[ 'email' ], as far as I can tell, to make:

```
$insert_fbacc="UPDATE jos_users SET email=" . $_POST[ 'email' ] . ", WHERE id='$user->id'";
```

Don't forget to escape characters!

Comment: There is a problem in the query, it would be: `UPDATE ... SET email=aaa@example.com ...`.